# Open a panel based on a string

Tags: java, string, swing, panel, jtabbedpane

A have a borderlayout panel. On the left side, I have a Jtree, where every node has his string name and the string name of a panel.

like this ...

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Opciones menu");
DefaultMutableTreeNode submenu;
submenu = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Entidades");
submenu.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Opc_mnu("Peliculas","mae_peli")));
submenu.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Opc_mnu("Sucursales","mae_suc")));
submenu.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Opc_mnu("Cines","mae_cin")));
submenu.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Opc_mnu("Circuitos","mae_cir")));
submenu.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Opc_mnu("Copias","mae_cop")));
```

, On the right side, I have a JTabbedpane (panel_pestanas) where I want to open the panel you have selected in the Jtree.

for example

```
panel_pestanas.add_Tab(((Opc_mnu) nodo_opcion).toString(),(JPanel) new mae_peli());
```

this works. But I want to make the panel name, variable.

Any idea?

Comment: Regarding, "But I want to make the panel name, variable" -- please explain as this is confusing, at least to me it is

Comment: If you mean that you'd like to give a variable a "name" based on a String, then don't, as that is not how Java works, and instead, you should consider using a Map to associate a String with an object.

Comment: *I have a JTabbedpane (panel_pestanas) where I want to open the panel you have selected in the Jtree.* - Instead of a JTabbedPane maybe you can use a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`. It allows you to swap panels based on a String value. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Hello Hovercarft, I want someone like :                                                                JPanel panelx=   ((Opc_mnu) nodo_opcion).getprograma();                                     and then                                                                       panel_pestanas.add_Tab(((Opc_mnu) nodo_opcion).toString(),(JPanel) new panelx);

Comment: 1) *"Hello Hovercarft,"* Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) Don't put code in a comment, where it is largely unreadable. Instead [edit] the question to add it. But please consider including a [mre] in the next edit.